# How do you begin a new loop when a certain character is found in a previous loop?

Tags: python, methods, boolean

Specifically, a user inputs a word. I want to compile a list of all the vowels and consonants used (no repeats, just a note of each one that is used). However, I only want to begin counting consonants AFTER the last vowel in the word is found.

For example, if the input is "hello", it should count e,o, but no consonants, as there are non after the last vowel, with a count vowels=2, consonants=0. If the input is "swarm" it should count a, r, m, vowels=1, consonants=2. "Book" would give you o,k,vowels=1, consonants=1.

There are other conditions I'd like the program to meet, but this one is the first step, and the most important to begin with.

Here's what I have, but it is not working as I need it to (as there is a line for each letter of the alphabet, I will just use quotation marks to show the continuation of the statements):

```
for i, ch in enumerate(word):
    if ch in VOWELS:
        if ch=="a" and ch not in VL:
            VL=VL+"a"
            VC+=1
        if ch=="e" and ch not in VL:
            VL=VL+"e"
            VC+=1
        #" " for each other vowel
    if ch not in VOWELS:
        if ch=="b" and ch not in CL:
            CL=CL+"b"
            CC+=1
        if ch=="c" and ch not in CL:
            CL=CL+"c"
            CC+=1
        #" " for each other consonant
print(VL[1:])
print(VC)
print(CL[1:])
print(CC)
```

I've tried indenting the consonant section to only begin after the vowel search is done, however, that does not seem to work. I need to index the location of the last vowel, and then start the consonant loop.

As a side not, we're only doing pretty basic commands, such as Boolean, concatenation, and string methods. No dictionaries or lists or things like that. I'm pretty sure there is a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only counting consonents after the first vowel, why don't you count every time, but reset the results whenever you find a vowel?

```
    if ch=="a" and ch not in VL:
        VL=VL+"a"
        VC+=1
        CL = ""  # add these two lines to each condition
        CC = 0
```

And since I can't resist, the code can be made much shorter and more efficient:

```
VL = set()
CL = set()

for ch in word:
    if ch in VOWELS:
        VL.add(ch)
        CL = set()
    else:
        CL.add(ch)

VC = len(VL)
CC = len(CL)
```

Comment: can't argue with shorter and more efficient! I'll try out resetting everything and see if it works with a few other conditions I need to add. The others are easier, so this should take care of any more woes.

Answer (score 0):

While you're looping over the word, you can also use your `i` value to loop backwards through its characters. Then, we use a boolean to determine whether our backwards search has hit a vowel yet or not, and only count consonants before the first vowel is hit:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

VL=''
VC=0

CL=''
CC=0

word = 'hello'
count_cons = True
for i, c in enumerate(word):
    if c in vowels and c not in VL:
        VL += c
        VC += 1

    if word[-i-1] in vowels:
        count_cons = False
    elif count_cons:
        CL += word[-i-1]
        CC += 1

print(VL)
print(VC)
print(CL)
print(CC)
```

This prints:

```
eo
2

0
```

If you wanted to shorten this down, you could do something like:

```
VL = set(c for c in word if c in vowels)
CL = set(c for i, c in enumerate(word) 
         if c not in vowels and all(x not in vowels for x in word[i+1:]))
VC = len(VL)
CC = len(CL)

print(VL)
print(CL)
print(VC)
print(CC)
```

Comment: Ah! Using the VL to count for the VC is much better than a separate command to add to it each time. That definitely shortens the code up. And the looping backwards should probably do the trick, although I will have to print them in reverse order... they need to appear in the print in order as they are written. But that can just be done by: print(CL[-1:], right?

Comment: Should be print(CL[::-1])

Comment: Yep, you could indeed do it like that. You could also change `CL += word[-i-1]` to `CL = word[-i-1] + CL` instead